# How to make a copy of a process template in TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I would like to make a copy of a TFS process template (the scrum one - though that's an irrelevant detail). I've used the Process Template Manager in Visual Studio 2013 to download a great bunch of xml that defines the template. What I am tempted to do is change the ProcessTemplate.xml in this way

```
 <metadata>
    <name>Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.4</name>
    <description>This template is for teams who follow the Scrum methodology and use Scrum terminology.</description>
    <version type="6B724908-EF14-45CF-84F8-768B5384DA45" major="3" minor="14" />
    <plugins>
      <plugin name="Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Classification" wizardPage="false" />
       <!-- more plugins -->
    </plugins>
  </metadata>
```

Change it to

```
  <metadata>
    <name>My new project</name>
    <description>My Description.</description>
    <version type="[A New Guid]" major="1" minor="1" />
    <plugins>
      <plugin name="Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Classification" wizardPage="false" />
      <!-- more plugins -->
    </plugins>
  </metadata>
```

So name, description, version and guid get changed. That's it - upload the template with Process Template Manager and I've got a template that I can tinker around with.

So is that correct? Is there anything else I need to do? I could just try it but I'm wary about doing something unpleasant to TFS. Or worse missing something out that only becomes apparent when the project is in mid-flight and using this template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is exactly what you should so. For reference some handy guidance to help you on you along:

- [ALM Ranger Guidance for Work Item Tracking customization](http://vsartfsptguide.codeplex.com/)
- [Work Item standard field reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194971.aspx)
- [Work Item XML Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237344.aspx)